# change creflabelformat

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm using the `cleveref` package and changed the `labelenumii` to `roman`, but I can't figure out how to change the `creflabelformat`(which is hopefully the right command)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii})}

\creflabelformat{enumii}{#2\roman{#1}#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item t
\begin{enumerate}
\item s \label{s}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

s is \cref{s}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no need to employ a `\creflabelformat` directive. It looks like you want to change the "look" of level-2 enumerated items from `(\alph{<counter>})` to `\roman(<counter>)`. If that's the case, you should replace the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii})}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}
```

In addition, if you want a cross-reference to a level-2 item not to show up as `1i` but just as `i`, i.e., if you want to omit the level-1 "prefix", you should provide the instructions

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{} % remove the cross-referencing prefix for level-2 items
\makeatother
```

as well.

An MWE -- `hyperref` and the `nameinlink` option are used to clarify visually what's produced by `\cref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item t
\begin{enumerate}
\item s \label{s}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
s is \cref{s}.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Just for the curious, the `article` document class sets up the following definitions of `\theenumii`, `\labelenumii` and `\p@enumii`:

```
\renewcommand\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
```

Comment: This happens if you just copy code...